# helping inequality for cyclic three variable inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $a\ge b \ge c\ge 0$ be reals and $a+b+c=3$ .Then prove
$$c(24a^2b+25)(b^2+ac)+50b(a^2+c^2)+5bc^2\le 200+3b^2c^4$$

this one has a proof replacing $b=3-a-c$ and then using calculus but uggly equations are obtained and i couldnt solve it by hand,just using wolframalpha,maby someone has an idea

Comment: How is that cyclic? Anyway, $b=c+x, a=c+x+y$ may be useful to substitute.

Comment: it is not cyclic